# mysql select from table B where condition is not met on table B directly, but through join on table A

Tags: mysql, join

Given two tables A and B, which look like:

```
+--------+      +--------------+
|Table A |      |Table B       |
+--------+      +------+-------+
|     id |      | A_id | Value | 
+--------+      +------+-------|
|      1 |      |    1 |   Cat |
|      2 |      |    1 |   Dog |
|      3 |      |    1 |   Pig |
|      4 |      |    3 |  Goat |
+--------+      |    3 |   Cow |
                |    4 |   Bee |
                +------+-------+
```

How can I select both Goat an Cow in table B, if my selection criteria is four letter words OR words which share an A_id with a four letter word?

I'm aware that I've phrased this question horribly, because I don't quite know what to ask. Even if you can't answer this question, but tidy it up so I might get an answer, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_b
WHERE A_id IN (SELECT A_Id
               FROM Table_b
               WHERE LENGTH(Value) = 4);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/GFU84662)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════╦═══════╗
║ A_id ║ Value ║
╠══════╬═══════╣
║    3 ║ Goat  ║
║    3 ║ Cow   ║
╚══════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: Thanks, you've answered the question as I've posed it, but I simplified my requirements too much when I posted it. My actual situation involves 7 tables joined together in a hierarchical fashion and I don't think your answer can be easily extended to my actual situation.